# setIconImage does not work when Jar is launched by a Windows 10 link

Tags: java, swing, jframe, icons, embedded-resource

What is wrong? Why is it that when the Jar is launched by a Windows 10 link that the wrong image icon (the regular Java icon, instead of the one that I put inside the Jar) gets displayed on the Windows 10 taskbar?

I have a Jar,  which tries to set its image icon with...

```
    this.setIconImage(icon);
```

It works fine,  when the program is launched with a command line like...

```
    java -jar C:\Games\RealWar.jar
```

The correct icon from inside the Jar shows up on the Windows 10 taskbar then (or when Eclipse runs the program),

but the correct icon does not show up on the taskbar,  when the Jar is launched by a Windows 10 link,  with the link containing a target string like...

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\Games\Java\RealWar.jar
```

In both cases,  the correct image icon shows up in the upper left hand corner of the program window,  but when the program is launched with a Windows 10 link,  instead of the command line,  the icon on the taskbar is the regular Java icon,  instead of the one inside the jar.

I guess I also want to point out that when the Jar is launched by a Windows 10 link,  the Jar is still finding its ImageIcon.  I know this,  because I set up a test in the program to...

```
    System.out.println("Icon is null.");
```

... if it can't find its Icon.   But I know that it is finding its Icon just fine,  because it says the other ...

```
    System.out.println("Icon is not null.");
```

...instead

I've also tried to shorten the target string in the Windows 10 link down to something like...

```
    java -jar "C:\Games\Java\RealWar.jar"
```

... but it does not work.  Windows 10 insists upon changing the "java" to either...

```
    "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe"
```

... or...

```
    C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe
```

and neither of those causes Windows 10 to display the correct Image Icon on the Windows 10 taskbar.

So what is wrong?  Why is it that when the Jar is launched by a Windows 10 link that the wrong image icon (the regular Java icon,  instead of the one that I put inside the Jar) gets displayed on the Windows 10 taskbar?

So the Image Icon is "not null".  The program in the Jar found its Image Icon.  It posted its image icon in the upper left corner of the program window.

But when the program is launched by a Windows 10 link,  instead of a command line,  only the regular Java Icon is displayed on the taskbar,  instead of the correct image icon.

Comment: The problem is how you are reading the image file. See [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource).

Comment: And how does the link icon look like? Is it a standard java icon or your image icon? When you create a link you can change its icon too.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: The reason why I went into so much detail was because I was hoping to not get a whole bunch of answers,  telling me to tweak my source code,  when that's not the problem.  My app is getting the resource just fine.

I was trying to explain that the difference is between when the app is launched from a command line,  versus when the app is launched from a Windows link.

Comment: The reason why I do not have the image file as an icon in the Windows link is because it is a 64x64 pixel png file.  Does anyone know how to convert a png file into something that Windows could use as an icon?

For some reason,  MicroSoft hasn't joined us in the 21st Century in letting us use png files as icons.

Comment: *"The reason why I went into so much detail was.."* Who are you replying to? Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.